# get original data in post.deserialization event of JMSSerializer

Tags: symfony, events, deserialization, jms-serializer

I need to use the post.deserialization event of JMSSerializer library to handle the case where linked resources can have different types.

My problem is that i have to work with the original data(non deserialize yet) with the aim of manual hydrate special fields.

Is it possible to get back these data ? and if it is possible how can i do that ?

thank you for your help.